# How do I clear the order cache?

Tags: 8, caching, ubercart

I manually update an order using the following code.

```
db_update('uc_orders') // Table name no longer needs {}
  ->fields(array(
    'order_status' => 'payment_received',
  ))
  ->condition('order_id', $order->order_id)
  ->execute();
```

Then I visit /admin/store/orders/view, but the value for the order still shows a *Pending*. If I clear the cache, the new status is *Payment received*, as it should be.

How do I clear the specific order cache so that it updates immediately?

The following code does what I want, but I would prefer clearing the cache for the specific order that is manually updated.

```
$orderEntity = Order::load($order_id);
$orderEntity->setStatusId('payment_received');
$orderEntity->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('commerce_order')->resetCache([ORDER_ID]);
```

This service which used in `OrderReassignTest.php` will help you to `Reload the order` based on `Order ID`.